# Completely empty page

Tags: 7

I need to create a page which is completely empty (no HTML returned at all). I need this for a POST callback (when using jEditable).
I would like to still have access to the global variables (such as `$user`) and the modules that I have installed as I have a module installed which lets me access my REST service.

However, even though there should be not HTML returned per default, I should be able to return a string.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that through a custom module - create a path and instead of returning the output, just print it.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function YOURMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['custom-url'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_blank_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Display the content for your blank page.
 */
function YOURMODULE_blank_page_callback() {
  print 'Your string.';
}
```